the default Nginx landing page is not getting
I have an ubuntu server 22.04. I installed Nginx, I didn't getting the landing page using public IP address.
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

this is my sites-available default config
` Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-05-12 20:02:43 UTC; 3min 52s ago Docs: man:nginx(8) Process: 10033 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Process: 10034 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Main PID: 10035 (nginx) Tasks: 2 (limit: 1116) Memory: 2.5M CPU: 26ms`
status is active
Status: active
To                         Action      From

Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
ufo status
how to access the Nginx landing page

Are you following some tutorial? What exactly did you do to enable nginx on your machine? What does curl -v http://your.server.ip.address/ print? Do you have access to nginx logs? Did you have a look at the logs?

curl -v  http:// ip address is giving the default Nginx page html in terminal.

[warn] 28844#28844: conflicting server name "_" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored, in error_log


I didn't getting the landing page using public IP address.
curl -v http:// ip address is giving the default Nginx page html in terminal

I'm think your hosting provider don't allow to access HTTP port 80. Maybe it firewall config on your host or hosting admin panels.
Please check it.
